# Changing Date format in VBA-excel

Tags: vba, excel, date, format

I have been working on a macro that changes dates from DD-MM-YY to DD-MM-YYYY and i would like to hear if it is possible to create a repeatable macro, that checks the date colum, and if it finds any DD-MM-YY dates, it will automatically change those to DD-MM-YYYY

Comment: There is no need to check. Just select the column you want to format and apply DD-MM-YYYY format to all cells.

Answer (score 0):

Try `.NumberFormat`:

```
Sub format_date()

Dim date_column As Range

With ActiveSheet

    With .Cells

    Set date_column = .Find(What:="date", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

    End With

    If date_column Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Cant find date column", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With date_column.EntireColumn

    .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy;@"

    End With

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Tank u warner! In the data i've been given, the dates have been written in as yy/mm/dd. It looks like it has been written in as numbers, and not in actual date format. We're trying to "flip" it from yy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yyyy, but the macro above does not locate the date format, and goes directly to the messagebox